# How to create a custom WPF XAML style for check box images

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a C# WPF Page and on it I have placed several small images that I want to act like check boxes (I have my own custom images for hover and selected states).

I am manually changing the images like so:

```
<Image x:Name="Image_Custom" Source="/Images/checkcircle_off.png" Width="16" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="30,107,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseEnter="Image_Custom_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Image_Custom_MouseLeave" MouseUp="Image_Custom_MouseUp" MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_Custom_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>


    private void Image_Custom_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_selected == false)
        {
            var uriSource = new Uri("/Images/checkcircle_hover.png", UriKind.Relative);
            Image_Custom.Source = new BitmapImage(uriSource);
        }
    }

    private void Image_Custom_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_selected == false)
        {
            var uriSource = new Uri("/Images/checkcircle_off.png", UriKind.Relative);
            Image_Custom.Source = new BitmapImage(uriSource);
        }
    }

    private void Image_Custom_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_selected)
        {
            var uriSource = new Uri("/Images/checkcircle_off.png", UriKind.Relative);
            Image_Custom.Source = new BitmapImage(uriSource);
            _selected = false;
        }
        else
        {
            var uriSource = new Uri("/Images/checkcircle_on.png", UriKind.Relative);
            Image_Custom.Source = new BitmapImage(uriSource);
            _selected = true;
        }
    }

    private void Image_Custom_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_selected)
        {
            var uriSource = new Uri("/Images/checkcircle_off.png", UriKind.Relative);
            Image_Custom.Source = new BitmapImage(uriSource);
            _selected = false;
        }
        else
        {
            var uriSource = new Uri("/Images/checkcircle_on.png", UriKind.Relative);
            Image_Custom.Source = new BitmapImage(uriSource);
            _selected = true;
        }
    }
```

This works but is very cumbersome and I will have up to 20 check boxes.

How can I create a custom XAML Style that I can use for each image or something similar.

**EDIT:**

I have used the following style to handle the hover over:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="checkBoxStyle">
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Images/checkcircle_off.png"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Images/checkcircle_hover.png"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

    <Image x:Name="Image_Custom" Style="{StaticResource checkBoxStyle}" Width="16" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="30,107,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseEnter="Image_Custom_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Image_Custom_MouseLeave" MouseUp="Image_Custom_MouseUp" MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_Custom_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
```

But I dont know how to handle the clicked event.  How can I do this?

**EDIT 2**

I have did the following:

```
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" x:Key="myCheckBoxStyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <Image x:Name="checkBoxImage" Source="/Images/checkcircle_off.png"></Image>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="checkBoxImage" Property="Source" Value="/Images/checkcircle_on.png"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="checkBoxImage" Property="Source" Value="/Images/checkcircle_off.png"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="checkBoxImage" Property="Source" Value="/Images/checkcircle_hover.png"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

<CheckBox Content="My CheckBox" Style="{StaticResource myCheckBoxStyle}" Width="16" Height="16" Foreground="white" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,242,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

The correct images appear when hovered, checked and unchecked.
But I noticed that the Content has disappeared ("My Checkbox") and also I only want the hover state to appear when its not checked, how can I do that?

Comment: I think you should take it in another way. Take a checkbox and make it react like a switching Image. The only thing you will have to do is to override CheckBox control and add properties to specify images for each state. Then you define a Style for your new Checkbox in which for different states you display a specified image.

Comment: ok ill try that, does the Checkbox have a 'IsMouseOver' property as well?

Comment: It has MouseOver state but no MouseOver property.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In WPF you generally look for a control that has the functionality you need and then you make it look like you want. So if you want `CheckBox` functionality then you use `CheckBox` control and change its `Template` to be what you want. So you can create `Style` for `CheckBox` that will set your custom `Template`

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" x:Key="myCheckboxStyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image x:Name="checkboxImage" Source="normal.png" Width="32"/>
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="checkboxImage" Property="Source" Value="checked.png"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="checkboxImage" Property="Source" Value="hover.png"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

and then just use it on any `CheckBox`

```
<CheckBox Style="{StaticResource myCheckboxStyle}" Content="ABC"/>
```

and you'll have all `CheckBox` functionality with your custom looks

Comment: Thanks dzoke, can you see my EDIT2 please

Comment: Check my edit by basically you need to use `ContentPresenter` for content and use `MultiTrigger` to set hover image

Comment: Never thought of it that way... Look for a control with the functionality you want, and then style it to look how you want. That's a game changer. Thanks!

Comment: Works great. I just added the attribute Cursor="Hand" to the <StackPanel> element for better usability.

Answer (score 1):

If you override CheckBox and create a specific style this will look like this:

```
public class MyCheckBox : CheckBox
{

    #region ImageNormal

    /// <summary>
    /// ImageNormal Dependency Property
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageNormalProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImageNormal", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(MyCheckBox),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((ImageSource)null));

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the ImageNormal property. This dependency property 
    /// indicates ....
    /// </summary>
    public ImageSource ImageNormal
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageNormalProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageNormalProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion

    #region ImageChecked

    /// <summary>
    /// ImageChecked Dependency Property
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageCheckedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImageChecked", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(MyCheckBox),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((ImageSource)null));

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the ImageChecked property. This dependency property 
    /// indicates ....
    /// </summary>
    public ImageSource ImageChecked
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageCheckedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageCheckedProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion

    //... other image properties removed for simplicity

    static MyCheckBox()
    {
        //Override base class style
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyCheckBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyCheckBox)));
    }


}
```

Associated XAML Style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <Grid>

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="grdNormal">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="grdMouseOver">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="grdPressed">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="grdNormal">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="imgUnchecked1">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="imgChecked1">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="imgUnchecked2">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="imgChecked2">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="imgUnchecked3">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="imgChecked3">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Grid x:Name="grdNormal">
                        <Image x:Name="imgUnchecked1" Source="{Binding ImageNormal, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        <Image x:Name="imgChecked1" Visibility="Collapsed" Source="{Binding ImageNormal, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid x:Name="grdMouseOver" Visibility="Collapsed">
                        <Image x:Name="imgUnchecked2" Source="{Binding ImageMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        <Image x:Name="imgChecked2" Visibility="Collapsed" Source="{Binding ImageMouseOverChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid x:Name="grdPressed" Visibility="Collapsed">
                        <Image x:Name="imgUnchecked3" Source="{Binding ImagePressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        <Image x:Name="imgChecked3" Visibility="Collapsed" Source="{Binding ImagePressedChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.  I'll look into using this method as well.